# Bar and line plot of the same color and line is behind the bars

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I want to have a bar plot and a line plot on the same axis.
The line plot should be above the bars, colors should cycle as would be expected with two consecutive calls to `plt.plot()`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xs = range(1,10)
    data = [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0.11, 0.09, 0.05, 0.07]
    benfords = [math.log10(float(d + 1)/d) for d in xs]

    plt.bar(xs, data, ec='black', label='Data1')
    plt.plot(xs, benfords, linestyle='--', marker='o', label="Benford's")

    plt.xlabel('Digit')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')

    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

This code generates this:

[image]

Also adding `zorder=1` and `zorder=2` (or with any two consecutive numbers like 3 and 4 etc.) doesn't help.
When `bar` is replaced with `plot` two line plot of different colors appear as expected.

Python version: 2.7.8
Matplotlib version: 2.2.5
OS: Windows 10 x64

Comment: It's matching because it's same color. Add "color = 'red'" to line plot line and you'll see difference

Comment: Sorry, it seems that their zorder actually is right! Thanks) But what about the color? Why doesn't it cycle further by the `prop_cycler`?

Comment: _"Why doesn't it cycle further by the `prop_cycler`?"_ Because the bars and the lines do not share a single `prop_cycle`,  each artist uses its own...  see the source code for `axes.bar` and `axes.plot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is a follow-up to [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69925232/bar-and-line-plot-of-the-same-color-and-line-is-behind-the-bars#comment123613438_69925232) by [the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6749234/daniel-kish)

> Why doesn't it cycle further by the prop_cycler?

The reason why is, even if the `prop_cycle` is loosely defined as a property of the `axes` (you retrieve it using `plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']`), in reality the `axes.bar` method and the `axes.plot` method, during initialization, instantiate separate copies of the cycler so, by default (as Matplotlib 3.4), the bars and the lines both start from blue

```
In [15]: fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ...: ax.bar((1,2,3), (5,4,6), label='b1')
    ...: ax.bar((1,2,3), (2,3,2), label='b2')
    ...: ax.plot((1,2,3),(9,6,8), label='l1')
    ...: ax.plot((1,2,3),(6,8,7), label='l2')
    ...: plt.legend()
    ...: plt.show()
```

[image]

Of course you can explicitly specify the color of each different set of bars, or of each line, but if you want to mix in the same axes bars and lines whose colors (and optionally other properties) obey a single, shared cycle, you must instantiate an appropriate `itertools.cycle` object by *calling* the axes `prop_cycle`

```
In [16]: fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ...: pc = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']() # we CALL the prop_cycle
    ...: npc = lambda: next(pc)
    ...: ax.bar((1,2,3), (5,4,6), label='b1', **npc())
    ...: ax.bar((1,2,3), (2,3,2), label='b2', **npc())
    ...: ax.plot((1,2,3),(9,6,8), label='l1', **npc())
    ...: ax.plot((1,2,3),(6,8,7), label='l2', **npc())
    ...: plt.legend()
    ...: plt.show()
```

[image]